# why did my computer come with FAT16 partition for EFI boot?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, fat32, fat16

I recently got an Intel Compute Stick with Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed.  From the factory, it has 4 partitions:

1. FAT16 boot 47.x MB
2. FAT32 microsoft data 1.x MB
3. ext4  Ubuntu 14.04 5.x MB
4. swap

Using `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo parted -l`, I confirmed that it is GPT/EFI.  I am confused why the partitions would be arranged like this. I have just started reading about partitions and installations, not knowing anything about it previously. However, from what I read, it seems like it should be a FAT32 boot partition of minimum 100 MB, with ideal of 512MB. Also, I don't understand why there is a "Microsoft data" partition, whatever that is.

Is there some advantage to having a FAT16 partition for boot? Is there ever an advantage to FAT16 over FAT32?

Answer (score 2):

FAT16 has a theoretical upper size limit of 2GB for a sector size of 512, more than enough for a 48 MB partition. The two advantages of having a FAT16 boot partition are:

- Most operating systems can use it, including Windows 95/98/NT/2000.
- It is efficient, both in speed and storage, on volumes smaller than 256 MB. This gives the Intel Compute Stick a shorter boot time.

The Microsoft data partition in an Intel Compute Stick with Lubuntu 20.04 installed on it wouldn't be used except if a Windows operating system is subsequently installed on a separate partition. The swap partition wouldn't be used by a fresh installation of Lubuntu 20.04 either because a fresh installation of Lubuntu 20.04 creates a swap file by default instead of a swap partition.

Comment: Hmmm...so, I installed Lubuntu 20.04 on the device and changed the boot partition to 100MB FAT32.  But you''re saying I should have kept it as FAT16 for faster boot time, huh?  50MB FAT16 boot partition would have been better than 100MB FAT32 partition for this small device?

Comment: FAT32 is the default file system for Ubuntu boot partitions. If anything bad happens to the boot partition you can easily repair it with [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/). Since you already have a 100MB FAT32 partition that works I recommend that you keep the existing 100MB FAT32 partition.

Comment: Curious though, doesn't this increase the chances of boot failure due to using unjournalled disks?

Comment: Partition 2 on the ICS is the restore image for the original 14.04 system.  So it's not needed for any other system, and the space may be incorporated into your root.